# Windows Phone 8.1 Create a Swipeable Scrollable Control

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to create an animation to a control.

So think of the animation and control of a now playing page on most touch screen devices. You see the control (album photo) and swipe either way and get it to slide off the screen and then the next control (album photo) slides on in its place.

I am not asking for you to code me this, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around a way that this could be done.

The control content is always changing, when you swipe one way, an image is removed from the view and then the next is added.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is `FlipView` control which can get you the interface you described.

Here are some references:

[Quickstart: Adding FlipView controls (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781233.aspx)

[XAML FlipView control sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-FlipView-control-0ae45312)